# People.asmx SearchPrincipals returns multiple values

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth

I am using SearchPrincipals function from webservice `People.asmx` to know the `UserInfoId` and display name corresponding to any user by providing `domain\login names`.

In SharePoint 2007 I am getting one entry for each `domain\login name`.

But in SharePoint 2010 and 2013 for claim based setup I am getting two entries for every user. Also for some users one of the value of `UserInfoId` is `-1`.

Can someone please tell me why are two values coming for same user in case of claim based setup?

Also please tell why `UserInfoId` is `-1` for some cases.